# homotopy class from $RP^n$ to $RP^m$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to see if any continuous map $f$ from $RP^n$ to $RP^m$ is null homotopic if $n<m$.

We know that $f$ is homotopic to a smooth map, so let's assume that $f$ is smooth.

Now consider the projection $g: S^n\rightarrow f$, then $f\circ g$ can be lifted to 
a smooth map $\tau$ from $S^n$ to $S^m$. Note that $\tau$ is null homotopic by a straight path homotopy (since $\tau$ is smooth, so there is no Peano curve stuff), note that this null homotopy descends to a map from $RP^n$ to $S^m$, which we can compose with the projection $S^m\rightarrow RP^m$ to give a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map.

Is my reasoning correct? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: No, because your homotopy is on a map $S^n\rightarrow S^m$, which doesn't necessarily descend to $RP^n\rightarrow RP^m$.  In fact, what you want to prove is not true.

Comment: You have the wrong order. It should be $n>m$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin  Do you mean that if $n>m$, then all continuous maps $RP^n\rightarrow RP^m$ are null homotopic?

Comment: The constant map is always null-homotopic. For $m>n$ the canonical inclusion is never null-homotopic, since it induces an isomorphism on $H^1$ (with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients). In fact there are no other homotopy classes, since the inclusion $\mathbb{R}P^m\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}P^\infty\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$ is $m$-connected. As far as I can tell, when $m=n$ the number of homotopy classes depends on the parity of $n$, and is either $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}$. The problem for $n>m$ is difficult in general. Note that there are is no group structure on these sets.